# Running Proc sort gives different estimates when using proc gee

Tags: sorting, statistics, sas, regression, cluster-analysis

Has someone else ever faced this situation:

I`m using **proc gee** to get a pulled estimate and then I`m using the **by statement** to have the stratified analysis.

In the **by statement** instead of using **proc sort** to sort based on the stratified variable, I use **where variable=0** and **where variable=1**.

Now, the weird thing is if I sort my data based on ID before getting the pulled estimates, I get different coefficient estimates, if I don't sort at all I get another set of estimates (which in this case, the pulled estimate doesn`t lay between the two stratified-estimate intervals) and if I sort based on my stratified variable I get another set of coefficient estimates.

I have never heard that we need to sort the data before running **proc gee** for pulled estimates but also why my estimates are not laying in the interval when my dataset is randomly sorted?, and why am I getting different estimates when I sort the dataset every time something different when I sort based on ID or based on sex (my stratified variable)!?

**Pulled estimate:**

proc gee data=data;

class x1 sex x2;

model y = x1 sex x2 x3 ;

repeated subject = x1 / type=un;

run;

**Stratified estimates:**

proc gee data=data;

where sex=1;

class x1 sex x2;

model y = x1 sex x2 x3 ;

repeated subject = x1 / type=un;

run;

proc gee data=data;

where sex=0;

class x1 sex x2;

model y = x1 sex x2 x3 ;

repeated subject = x1 / type=un;

run;

**My expected outcome:**

the beta estimates for x2 and x3 in stratified analysis(sex=0/1) <the beta estimates for x2 and x3 in pulled analysis< the beta estimates for x2 and x3 in stratified analysis(sex=0/1)

**My remedy:**
proc sort data=data; by ID (and once by sex); run;

Getting a complete different estimates yet not getting the expected outcome